# why when i change slaying in the last else statment it crashes the browser

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

i was playing around in code academy and for some reason when i change the last slaying i the else statement to true instead of making the person invincible it just crashes my browser any ideas why thank you in advance

```
 var slaying = true;
 var youHit = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
 var damageThisRound = Math.floor(Math.random()* 5 + 1);
 var totalDamage = 0;

 while (slaying){

    if (youHit)
    {
        console.log("how can you hit an emaginary creature");
        totalDamage += damageThisRound;
        if (totalDamage >= 4)
        {
            console.log("you slew the imagenary dragon");
            slaying = false;
        }
        else
        {
            var youHit = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("you defeated yourself because dragons dont exist");
        slaying = true;//i changed it from false
    }

 }
```

Comment: Because you have a while that acts on the `slaying` variable

Comment: bu tin the if statement i have one that is false so it should keep on slaying until it kills the dragon and then hit a false statement

Comment: You never change `youHit`, so you will always end up in the else clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> while (condition) { }
> ```

A while loop loops as long as the condition is true

> ```
> if (condition) { } else { }
> ```

An if else statement continues to the else statement if the condition is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).

In your case you have `youHit = false` (or equal to 0) and `slaying = true`. Since the while loop loops as long as slaying is true and since you don't change youHit to true you will end up with an endless loop, and the browser will happily execute the same statement over and over again, never breaking from the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

`Math.random()` returns either a `0` or up to, but not including, `1`. Since you use `Math.floor()` on that result, the likelihood of `youHit` equaling `0` is quite high. Thus, you will never exit the loop when that condition occurs.